# Photos tagged with brand are not showing in Facebook fan page photos tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

I manage a Facebook fan page for a brand and fans are able to tag my brand on photos. 
According to [what I've read on someone's blog](http://www.robertoiacono.it/come-taggare-le-pagine-fan-page-nelle-foto-di-facebook/), photos where my page have been tagged should appear on the photos tab of the brand's account.

But I don't see them. Why don't they appear?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to explicitly post the photos to the brand page. I believe the page owner still gets the notifications though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the permissions:

1. Edit Page
2. Manage permissions